# Imagemagick Composite Overlay Opacity

Tags: imagemagick, composite

I am using imagemagick to overlay one image over another with a blending option. I'd like to adjust the overlaying image opacity to about 60%. I would only like to adjust the foreground image, not the merged group. I Currently have:

```
exec("convert $img_in test_images/test_opacity.jpg -compose screen -composite $img_out");
```

And I'd like something like this:

```
exec("convert $img_in (test_images/test_opacity.jpg -opacity 0.6) -compose screen -composite $img_out");
```

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [+level](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#level), or [-level-color](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#level-colors) options to adjust the white/black points. This will generally give the mask the effects of "dodging" or "burning"; which, compose `Screen` will respect.

```sh
convert source.jpg \
        \( mask.jpg -normalize +level 0,60% \) \
        -compose screen -composite destination.jpg
```

You can also adjust the opacity of the mask by defining an alpha channel with [-alpha](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#alpha),  [-channel](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#channel) & [-evaluate](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#evaluate). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13373719/438117). But this wouldn't work with compose `Screen` as it's expecting a range between black & white.

```sh
convert source.jpg \
        \( mask.jpg -alpha set -channel A -evaluate set 60% \) \
        -compose screen -composite \
        destination.jpg
```

Comment: For me, the 2nd command worked better without the -compose screen param. It would not be opaque at 100% and rather do some weird multiply thingy